# PHP @ variables

Tags: php, variables

I saw a piece of code from a website which is in php.  In that code variable are written @ symbol at front what does that mean
eg :

@hello = "hi";

Comment: I can only imagine this is a typo; can you provide a link to the relevant webpage?

Comment: That's actually a parse error, it's not valid PHP code.

Comment: Or perhaps Perl? My Perl is creaking from rust, but it did have `@var` notation IIRC. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@` is error suppression operator in PHP.

```
PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (@). 
When prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be 
generated by that expression will be ignored.
```

**EDIT:**

Typical usage include the following:

```
<?php
// Usage of the @ symbol in PHP code

// Typical Example
$var = @some_function();

// Class/Object Example
$var = @new some_class();

// Does NOT Work!
//$var = new @some_class(); // syntax error

// Another example. Very slow
$var = @$some_var;

?>
```

See the following links:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

http://michelf.com/weblog/2005/bad-uses-of-the-at-operator/

Comment: And the syntax is: `$someVar = @SomeFunction();` Meaning that every error or exception is thrown in SomeFunction it is discarded.

Comment: That's nice and all, but the posted example code will not execute due to a parse error.

Comment: And that is why I have also included a link on 'Bad use of the at operator' in my answer above.

Comment: And how exactly does that explain that `@foo` is a syntax error and not your purported error suppression operator? Your answer does not answer the question.

Comment: This answer is just simply plain wrong, the example in the question produces a syntax error and doesn't suppress an error. -1

Answer (score 0):

@ can not be used with variable without a $. It is syntax error.

Comment: Well, `echo @foo;` would actually work and output "foo". Just assignment won't work.

Comment: In this case foo is undefined constant. Not a variable. It outputs as string and PHP notice fired. But @ suppressed it. Looks like write-only. Don't do this at home =)