# What exactly does the @ symbol in front of new mean?

Tags: php, pdo

I have some one question for this code

```
self::$connect = @new PDO(
            "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$databes",
            $user,
            $password,
            self::$setting
        );
```

What exactly does the **@** symbol in front of **new** mean?

I try to find in the manuals why @ is written when creating a PDO and I still can't find the answer.

Very thanks for answer.

Comment: [error control operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

Comment: This would help https://stackoverflow.com/a/9835960/17788846

Comment: It suppresses errors and should be avoided when ever possible. It's really bad practice to have those. Hiding errors makes debugging a real pain. In this case, make PDO throw exceptions on errors and handle the exceptions in your application properly instead.

Comment: The most stupid thing that ever can be done

Comment: *Also* `self::$connect` is not overly smart move too.

Comment: It means that whoever wrote the code you're reusing didn't care about managing errors and exceptions. While `@` is technically called _error control operator_, it's usually read as **"Steer clear of this code or spend your eternity chased by ghosts"** by coders of experience. You know, `@ @ @ . . .` <-- these are the guys chasing `. . (<` PacMan since the ancient of days.